# Swagger: How to have a property reference a model in OpenAPI 2.0 (i.e. nest the models)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how I can nest models in OpenAPI 2.0.

Currently I have:

```yaml
SomeModel:
 properties:
   prop1:
     type: string
   prop2:
     type: integer
   prop3:
     type:
       $ref: OtherModel

OtherModel:
  properties:
    otherProp:
      type: string
```

I have tried many other ways:

```yaml
prop3:
  $ref: OtherModel
# or
prop3:
  schema:
    $ref: OtherModel
# or
prop3:
  type:
    schema:
      $ref: OtherModel
```

None of the above seem to work.

However, with arrays works just fine:

```yaml
prop3:
  type: array
  items:
    $ref: OtherModel
```

Comment: Tried exact the same variants until i found @Ron's solution here:D

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The correct way to model it in OpenAPI 2.0 would be:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

definitions:
  SomeModel:
    type: object
    properties:
      prop1:
        type: string
      prop2:
        type: integer
      prop3:
        $ref: '#/definitions/OtherModel'   # <-----

  OtherModel:
    type: object
    properties:
      otherProp:
        type: string
```

If you use OpenAPI 3.0, models live in `components/schemas` instead of `definitions`:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
...

components:
  schemas:
    SomeModel:
      type: object
      properties:
        prop1:
          type: string
        prop2:
          type: integer
        prop3:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/OtherModel'   # <-----

    OtherModel:
      type: object
      properties:
        otherProp:
          type: string
```

Remember to add `type: object` to your object schemas because the [type is not inferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47390723/113116) from other keywords.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to use a shared schema add some more properties to that schema ? something like:
```
 *       200:
 *         description: Returns the formatted user data
 *         content:
 *           application/json:
 *             schema:
 *               type: object
 *               properties:
 *                 info:
 *                   type: object
 *                   $ref: '#/components/schemas/User'
 *                   properties:
 *                     anotherProp:
 *                       type: string
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another trick that works. This solution applies to OpenAPI 3 – the latest version of the OpenAPI Specification as the point of answering this question.

**Here's how**:

Say, I have a `User` model with a `State` enum. I defined the `State` enum in a different schema and then referenced it in the `User` schema.

```
components:
  schemas:
    User:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        first_name:
          type: string
        last_name:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
          format: password
        state:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/State'
    State:
      type: string
      description: List of States
      enum:
        - State 1
        - State 2
        - State 3
        - State 4
        - State 5
```

Note that the enums were represented as arrays here, if you would love to represent them as hashes, check out this solution on [Representing enum property in hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60839860/10907864).

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: What if I had another ref for those properties `    id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        first_name:
          type: string
        last_name:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
          format: password` How would I combine them with the ref to the sate property ?

Comment: It is very interesting I cannot include `state.description` below `state.$ref`.