# Expressing loopback relations with swagger

Tags: swagger, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

Is there a standardized or recommended way of translating the relations between loopback models to the definitions part of the swagger yaml?

Things I'm unsure about:

- When giving a relation by [referencing the other model definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26410540/4745878), do circular references (eg. A hasOne B, B belongsTo A) become a problem?
- Could one instead pass a reference to the id of the related model instance? This could simplify POST requests a lot.
- How to precisely translate the meaning of the relation