# How to document eager loaded objects in OpenAPI 3

Tags: rest, openapi

We have the following situation: In our API we can eager load other projects like this `/user?includes=projects` this results in a nested response

```
{
  "name": "John",
  ...
  "projects": [
    {
      "title": "Example"
      ... 
    }
  ]
}
```

If we call the endpoint without the includes `/user` the response does not include the projects

```
{
  "name": "John",
  ...
}
```

How would you document this in OpenAPI 3?

Comment: `projects` is an optional property of the User schema. See [How to define nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35955243/113116) and [How to specify if a field is optional or required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40113049/113116).

Comment: @Helen thank you. I am aware of the required field. But code generation wise this would lead to validation rules for the `project` attribute.