# How to use $ref within a schema in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi

I want to represent the following JSON as a `schema` in an OpenAPI 3.0 API definition:

```
{
get-question: {
  question-id:string
  }
}
```

So far, I have written:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
  #schema of a question-id
    QuestionID:   #{question-id: string}
      properties:
        question-id:
          type: string
      required:
        - question-id

  #schema of a get-question request which contains a question id      
    GetQuestion: #{get-question: {question-id:string}}
      properties:
        get-questions:
          type: $ref:'#/components/schemas/QuestionID'
      required:
        - get-questions
```

but I am getting these errors in the Swagger Editor:

```
Schema error at components.schemas['GetQuestion']
should have required property '$ref'
missingProperty: $ref
Jump to line 79
Schema error at components.schemas['GetQuestion']
should match exactly one schema in oneOf
Jump to line 79
Schema error at components.schemas['GetQuestion'].properties['get-questions']
should have required property '$ref'
missingProperty: $ref
Jump to line 81
Schema error at components.schemas['GetQuestion'].properties['get-questions']
should match exactly one schema in oneOf
Jump to line 81
Schema error at components.schemas['GetQuestion'].properties['get-questions'].type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: array, boolean, integer, number, object, string
Jump to line 82
```

What is the correct syntax for `$ref`?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Property reference to Model on Swagger (nesting)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26287962/113116)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$ref` is used *instead* of `type`, not as the value of `type`. Also note the space after `:` to separate the key and value in YAML.

```yaml
        get-questions:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/QuestionID'
```

You also need to add `type: object` to your `QuestionID` and `GetQuestion` schemas to indicate that they are objects; the `properties` keyword alone is not enough.

There also seems to be a typo in one of the property names - it's `get-questions` (plural) in the `GetQuestion` schema but `get-question` (singular) in your JSON example. I guess it should be `get-question`.

Complete example:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    # schema of a question-id
    QuestionID:      # {question-id: string}
      type: object   # <-----
      properties:
        question-id:
          type: string
      required:
        - question-id

    #schema of a get-question request which contains a question id      
    GetQuestion:     # {get-question: {question-id:string}}
      type: object   # <-----
      properties:
        get-question:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/QuestionID'   # <-----
      required:
        - get-questions
```

Comment: I think you meant `get-question` instead of the last `get-questions`