# OpenApi 3.0: a reference to the existing class

Tags: swagger, openapi

I want to use a class from a library as a type of a property. Say it is `foo.lib.Foo`.
What is the right way to properly define it as a type of the property?

```
SomeDto:
  type: object
  properties:
     foo:
        $ref: `foo.lib.Foo`???
```

Comment: An OpenAPI definition doesn't have visibility into external Java/etc. libraries, all schemas (classes) must be defined in your OpenAPI file. See also [How to have a property reference a model in OpenAPI (i.e. nest the models)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26410540/113116)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done through defining a type mapping and referring the type explicitly.

1. Define a type mapping in the plugin configuration

```
    <configuration>
         ...
         <importMappings>
             <importMapping>Foo=foo.lib.Foo</importMapping>
         </importMappings>
         ...
    </configuration>
```

2. Refer the type:

```
SomeDto:
  type: object
  properties:
     foo:
        $ref: '#/components/schema/Foo'
```

3. Include the dependency of the library in the classpath (the `dependencies` section).

**UPDATE** in case it still doesn't work, try to refer your class as follows:

```
SomeDto:
  type: object
  properties:
     foo:
        $ref: 'Foo'
```

Comment: `type: Foo` is not a valid type in an OpenAPI definition, the `type` values are predefined. Do you maybe mean `foo: {$ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'}` where `Foo` is defined as `type: object` (i.e. free-form object)?

Comment: Nope, this is exactly like I wrote and it works perfectly fine: the generated classes contain proper full names of the resolved type (`foo.lib.Foo` in the class code)

Comment: This does not work.  I have tried to import a class that is defined within a maven dependency using the accepted answer and I can confirm it does not work.  You basically get the error.  My maven pom contains.

<importMappings>       
     <importMapping>MyClass=com.org.project.MyClass</importMapping>
</importMappings>

Errors: 
 -Could not find components/schemas/MyClass in contents of ./ird-db-dao-service.json

Comment: @juckky can you try with `schemaMappings` ? like this :
<schemaMappings>Foo=foo.lib.Foo</schemaMappings>
I could import the missing type like this. openapi-generator-maven-plugin V. 6.5.0

Answer (score 1):

You can config `pom.xml` with maven plugin as following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openApi3.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <language>java</language>
                <!- add schema mapping to existing Java class ->
                <schemaMappings>CrifInfo=com.test.Crif</schemaMappings>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then refer to `CrifInf` in the openApi3.yaml

```
components:
  schemas:
    CrifNote:
      type: object
      properties:
        name: 
          $ref: 'CrifInfo'
```