# how to write swagger document for nested objects

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

this document is ready for Nodejs create API, how to write swagger document for nested objects.
Here below is my full swagger document code. but it doesn't show user object. help me to fix the issue

```
@swagger
/api/v1/employees/add:
  post:
    tags:
      - Employees
    summary: "Create a new employee"
    description:  
    produces:
      - application/json
    security:
     - api_key: []
     - api_token : [] 
    parameters:
      - name: body
        in: body
        description:
        required: true
        schema:
            type: "object"
            properties:
              employee_code:
               type: "string"
              mobilenumber:
               type: "string"
              firstname:  
               type: "string"
              lastname:
               type: "string"
              emailid:
               type: "string"
              is_login_enabled:
               type: "boolean"
              address_line1:  
               type: "string"
              address_line2:
               type: "string"
              town:
               type: "string"
              city:
               type: "string"
              state:  
               type: "string"
              pincode:
               type: "string"
              designation:
               type: "string"
              joining_date:
               type: "string"
               format: "date-time"
              releiving_date:
               type: "string"
               format: "date-time"
              is_active:  
               type: "boolean"
              account_id:  
               type: "number"
        user:
            type: "object"
            properties:
              username:
               type: "string"   
              role_id:
               type: "number"
              reference_object:  
               type: "string"
               example: "employees"
              password:
               type: "string"
              password_secret:
               type: "string"
    responses:
      200:
        description: Employee created successfully
      204:
        description: No data found
```

here is the snap of swagger ui
[image]

Comment: Related (or duplicate) [Swagger: How to have a property reference a model in OpenAPI 2.0 (i.e. nest the models)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26287962/113116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For nested object it is simple just define properties below with an indentation so your route definition would be

```
@swagger
/api/v1/employees/add:
  put:
    tags:
      - Employees
    summary: "Create a new employee"
    description:  
    produces:
      - application/json
    security:
     - api_key: []
     - api_token : [] 
    parameters:
      - name: body
        in: body
        description:
        required: true
        schema:
           type: "object"
           properties:
              employee_code:
                 type: "string"
              mobilenumber:
                 type: "string"
              firstname:  
                 type: "string"
              lastname:
                 type: "string"
              emailid:
                 type: "string"
              is_login_enabled:
                 type: "boolean"
              address_line1:  
                 type: "string"
              address_line2:
                 type: "string"
              town:
                 type: "string"
              city:
                 type: "string"
              state:  
                 type: "string"
              pincode:
                 type: "string"
              designation:
                 type: "string"
              joining_date:
                 type: "string"
                 format: "date-time"
              releiving_date:
                 type: "string"
                 format: "date-time"
              is_active:  
                 type: "boolean"
              account_id:  
                 type: "number"
              user:
                 type: "object"
                 properties:
                    username:
                       type: "string"   
                    role_id:
                       type: integer
                    reference_object:  
                       type: "string"
                       example: "employees"
                    password:
                       type: "string"
                    password_secret:
                       type: "string"
    responses:
      200:
        description: Employee created successfully
      204:
        description: No data found
```

It looks like this in the Swagger UI.
[image]

Make sure to have the proper indentations when placing it.