# In Swagger with openapi 3.0, my nested object scheme is not being displayed

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0, swagger-jsdocs

I'm working in a nodeJS project with express framework, i am using swagger-jsdoc and swagger-ui-express, also i'm writing my configuration in yaml file. I want to documents my services but i have some problems when i try to display nested objects. Simply, i cant see nothins when i expand the tree of nested objects. Please help.

```
[Swagger definition][1]
[My yaml file][2]
[Result in browser][3]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/by9EU.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMyXN.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHwlt.png
```

Comment: can you add `yaml` configuration to question for more detail?

Comment: Please post your files and code **as text** instead of images. Use the `{ }` button to format text as code.

Comment: Related: [How to have a property reference a model in OpenAPI 2.0 (i.e. nest the models)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26287962/113116)

Comment: Unfortunately, We need more details to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A property whose value is an instance of another object is defined like this:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    ...
    BuilderElementRequest:
      type: object
      properties:

        pageSectionElementRequest:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/PageSectionElementRequest'   # <---------

        removedElements:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
```

To add a custom example (i.e. override the default example) for a referenced schema in OpenAPI 3.0.x, you need to wrap the `$ref` into `allOf`:

```yaml
        pageSectionElementRequest:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PageSectionElementRequest'
          example:
            element: '11112'
```