# How to reference a model in a POST request body schema according to OpenAPI?

Tags: post, swagger, backend, openapi

I would like to describe a POST method using the OpenAPI standards. The POST takes in an application/json body schema that has some properties. One of these properties is already defined in a defined models section. I have this yaml file:

```
summary: "Creates a new Plant Unit."
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
parameters:
  - name: plantunit
    in: body
    type: string
    schema:
      type: object
      required:
        - plant_guid
        - code
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
        plant_guid:
          type: string
        parent_guid:
          type: string
        name_translation:
          type: object
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/NameTranslations'
```

The `name_translation` property is used in many POST/PUT/PATCH methods of this API, so I have it defined as follows:

```
NameTranslations
  type: object
  properties:
    EN: 
      type: string
    ES:
      type: string
    PT: 
      type: string
```

However that doesn't seem to work. The Swagger page shows the `name_translation` property but without the schema defined in the model.

[image: Schema model in the request body]

Below is the name translations:

[image: Name translations model]

Am I missing something here? Thanks to anyone who spends time reading this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to have a property reference a model in OpenAPI 2.0 (i.e. nest the models)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26287962/113116)

Comment: @Helen I did try that method, however I may have skipped something and it didn't work. I just tried again and it worked out! Thanks for the comment. I think this question may now be marked as duplicate or deleted.